# Novel about infinite earths, zombie virus killing humans on each earth

Tags: story-identification

I read this book hastily a few years back and wish to re-read it, slowly this time.  The theme is that of an infinite universe in which earth is replicated infinite times and we here on this earth have developed the means to connect with other earths.  The title was "Black*** Mountain" or similar.  Every earth contacted in the institute inside this mountain is being ravaged by a zombie type plague and it transpires the plague is purposely being let loose on each earth by a religious cult centred on one such earth.

I hope someone can relate the title and/or author of this fine SF book.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18248556-coldbrook?

Comment: Yes!  Thank you very much indeed.  Now I can locate it in my public library system and re-read.  Well done :)

Comment: I see you're still active on the network; please consider accepting Valorum's answer by clciking the checkmark on the left, as you confirmed it was the right one :)

Answer (score 1):

This is [Coldbrook](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18248556-coldbrook) by Tim Lebbon

> Coldbrook is a secret laboratory located deep in Appalachian Mountains. Its scientists had achieved the impossible: a gateway to a new world. Theirs was to be the greatest discovery in the history of mankind, but they had no idea what they were about to unleash.
>
> With their breakthrough comes disease and now it is out and ravaging the human population. The only hope is a cure and the only cure is genetic resistance: an uninfected person amongst the billions dead.